# Appium2.0 server not starting in MacOS

Tags: macos, appium

1. I have installed Appium 2.0 using the command

   npm install -g appium@next
2. Then installed the driver using below commands:

   appium driver install xcuitest
   appium driver install uiautomator2
3. After this when tried to run the Appuium server using command:

   Appium
4. As if we see the screenshot added by me, it displayed "No Plugins  is installed", I have installed a driver and also activated it. But still it was not proceeding further.

But it is getting stuck at some point and not preceding further.
Please check attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appium plugins are not the same as the drivers you are mentioning. you can use the command: `appium plugin list` in your terminal to see the available plugins. This is not an error, you just have to start the driver using your desired capablities, check following link: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/